# How to get the plane out of a arbitrary collection of points?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, linear-algebra

I've got a arbitrary collection of 3d points, i know they're coplanar, but how do i calculate that plane?

Comment: Btw, I think the correct term is coplanar, meaning they share a plane.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take any three distinct points, and form a triangle of non-zero area. Compute the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two of the triangle's sides. That gives you the plane's normal, and you can use the common point as a point on the plane.

A point on a plane plus a normal [defines a plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Definition_with_a_point_and_a_normal_vector).

Comment: @Niyaz: Of course. I edited to make it clearer what is required of the points selected.

Comment: The easy way to check that three points are distinct and not colinear is that the cross-product of those vectors is non-zero. No need for the code to calculate the area of the triangle.

Comment: @onebyone: True. I didn't mean that literally, I meant "the points must form a triangle with non-zero area". How to do the testing is a separate question, piggy-backing on the cross product sounds like a great choice.

Comment: @bzlm: nice to see French on this barbaric site from times to times!

Answer (score 4):

If they're not all planar, calculate the coefficients of the plane using a least squares fit.

The equation for a plane is Ax + By + Cz = D, so plug in your points and solve for the four unknown coefficients.

UPDATE: Just curious - how do you "know" that all the points are in the same plane?  What makes you so certain?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that they are co-planar, pick three points, and try this:

http://www.jtaylor1142001.net/calcjat/Solutions/VPlanes/VP3Pts.htm

Answer (score 2):

Because any three non-colinear points define a plane, a possible answer is...

Simply grab the first three points that are not colinear.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to define a plane is a function from two parameters to a point. If you have three points A,B,C, then the function `f(i,j) = A + (B-A)i + (C-A)j` covers all the points on the plane.

Depending on your application it may be useful to normalise the `b = (B-A)` and `c = (C-A)` vectors to be perpendicular and of unit length. Unit length is easy.

In order to make them perpendicular, first normalise b, then take the dot product of b and c. This is the amount the the c vector points in the same direction as b, so substract this from c. `c = c - (b.c)b` Finally normalise c (i.e. divide by it's length)